# Lipschitz Continuity-Function

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

I cannot prove that $A\cos(ax+b)$, where $A$, $a$, $b$ are real numbers is Lipschitz continuous. Am I wrong for trying to do so using the definition?

Comment: My guess would be to use mean value theorem. Not sure though.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! I would like to point out that I'm _not_ well acquainted with real analysis then, please, make sure to proofread what I wrote before using it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is Lipschitz continuous, there must be some constant $K$ such that the function satisfies
$$
|A \cos(ax_1+b)-A\cos(ax_2+b)|\leq K|x_1-x_2|
$$
for all $x_1$ and $x_2$. The RHS is bounded by the maximum possible difference, which is $2A$ (if $ax_1+b$ and $ax_2+b$ are separated by a multiple of $\pi$). Therefore, the RHS will be $2A$ if
$$
(ax_1+b)-(ax_2+b)=n\pi
$$
$$
x_1-x_2=\frac{n\pi}{a}, \ n\geq1.
$$
Therefore, our inequality is
$$
K \geq \frac{2Aa}{n\pi}
$$
If you chose $K = 2Aa/\pi$ you can ensure the inequality. Therefore, since we found $K$, the function is Lipschitz continuous.